# Logback file with Kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, logging, kubernetes-helm, logback

I have a microservice application based on SpringBoot and deployed on Kubernetes with Helm Chart.

I'd like to continue to use the logback file we used previously to write the application logs in a formatted way.

This is my `logback.xml` file we used in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="10 seconds" debug="true">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="com.netflix" level="WARN"/>
</configuration>
```

This is my `configmap.xml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.app.name }}-configmap
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
data:
  application.yml : |+
    server:
      ssl:
        enabled: false
```

I don't know how to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `logback.xml` file to the root folder of the Helm Chart template.

This is the structure of the folder:

```
├── app-root
│   ├── logback.xml
│   ├── values
│   ├── template
│       ├── configmap.xml
│       ├── deployment.xml
│       ├── ...
```

then, add in the `configmap.yml` file the import of that file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.app.name }}-configmap
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
data:
  application.yml : |+
    server:
      ssl:
        enabled: false
  logback.xml : |+
{{ .Files.Get "base-logback.xml" | indent 4 }}
```